# Dynamically add widgets to a dashboard using backbone.js and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, dashboard

I'm coding a Dashboard of a Web-CMS app using Backbone.js and several jQuery plugins.
This dashboard should be as intuitive and customizable as possible and highly extendable at once.

Now, what I want to do, is to load a widget's data and it's template by an api via ajax.
In fact, that isn't a problem but I wanted to ask you about a best practice to load template data (HTML/javascript/etc...) with javascript via ajax.

I could make multiple ajax calls where I first receive an html snippet with the template and then load it's data in a second request as a JSON string.

```
// first request
<h6>Some HTML Stuff here</h6>
// second request
{"id": "5", "name": "Example Widget"}
```

Or I could store the template itself in a JSON string which on the other side would reduce server-load but feels kind of wrong.

```
// single request
{"id": "5", "name": "Example Widget", "template": "<h6>Some HTML stuff here"</h6>"}
```

Any suggestions or other methods?

Comment: Can't you include the templates in your application using one of the many client side templating options (e.g. underscore, handlebars etc.), and then only request the data instead of the data and template?

Comment: @MattiJohn I should have stated out that I want the widgets to act like some sort of modules you plug in on the server backend. So widgets and the actual dashboard script are separated. No way to include them into the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 request method is they way I have personally went when setting this up.  The overhead for the separate call was not worth the worry of trying to process the data in the browser.  If you would really like to minimize the number of calls, combining JSON responses will probably be the most efficient way.

I would recommend using require.js as it manages most of this for you.

http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/

Comment: Ok, but isn't it against the JSON "rules" to store actual html in a JSON string? I found a JSON templating plugin for jquery [here](http://json2html.com/). But that doesn't seem to be very intuitive either.

Comment: The html would be stored in a separate file and a templating engine would combine the two.  Since you are using backbone I would recommend the underscore template function.  The templating engine you use is definitely a preference, there isn't a "best" one.  http://underscorejs.org/#template